# Unable to see Rendered messages in logs for Ruby on Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby

I have recently upgraded from Ruby on Rails from 5.2 to 6.1 . Everything works fine but i am unable to see the rendered messages in the logs. Not able to understand the reason and solution for this.
(I am not sure if i can mention the logs here because of company policies.)
The widgets and everything are rendering on the testing page but not able to see them in logs.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels. You need to adjust the log_level.

Comment: I tried changing the log level to debug in production.rb file and the rendered log showed. but i wanted them to be shown as info log not as debug logs what can i do for that? @razvans

Comment: `config.log_level = :info` ?

Comment: @razvans its already info inside the production.rb . But still unless i write another statement for debug no rendered message show up not even when i change the pre written comfig.log_level  = :info statement to :debug .Only way to show the messages is to let the info statement be there and add one another for debug. But as i told before i want the rendered messages as info not debug because debug brings unnecessary logs inside production environment.